# Why does the official AOSP website discourage OEMs from implementing support for audio accesory mode usb c to aux adapters?

Tags: audio, headphone-jack, usb-c

I stumbled across some [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/usb-adapter) from the AOSP project that encourages OEMs to only support digital to analog usb c to aux jack adapters which contain their own dac to convert the digital audio coming from the phone's usb c port to analog for the aux jack. What's so bad about supporting an analog only adapter that uses the phone's existing dac to convert the digital signal to analog and simply treat it's usb c port as if it were an analog headphone jack? Audio accessory mode at least on paper seems like a complete no brainer since it means the adapters are cheaper because they don't need to have their own dac.